# How new key word effecting the JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Counting with a local variable.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function Add(x) {
    this.counter = x;
   return function () {return this.counter += 1;}
};
var add = Add(0);
```

when I replaced `"var add = Add(0);"` with `"var add = new Add(0)"` the output is showing "NaN". why? and how this is actually working?

```
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add(); 
  for each click 1, 2, 3 ....

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`new` is used to create a new instance, based on an existing definition (which you are storing in `Add`). Instead of an instance being generated, you're returning a function, so it is not working out as you expected.

This form should work:

```
function Add(x) {
    this.counter = x;

    this.addOne = function() {
        return this.counter += 1;
    }
}

var add = new Add(0);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add.addOne();
}
```

As to your question about why your code was returning `NaN`, let's look at what you were doing:

```
function Add(x) {
    this.counter = x;
    return function () {return this.counter += 1;}
};
var add = new Add(0);
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add(); 
}
```

Here you declare a variable `add` and initialize it using `new Add(0)`. First, the `Add` function declares a property in its own scope named `counter` and assigns it the value passed in via the parameter named `x` (0, in this case). Then, it returns a function. Then it exits, no longer required, and is garbage-collected. The value assigned to the `counter` property is discarded because the `this` it is attached to has gone out of scope.

You now have `add` as a pointer to a function. It does not have a property named `counter`. When you invoke the `add()` function, it tries to add 1 to `this.counter`. Since `this.counter` is not defined, it automatically has the value `undefined`.

If you try to add a number to `undefined`, you get `NaN`. Since this happens in a `return` statement, `NaN` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `Add(0)` and `new Add(0)` is that the first one calls the function within the `window` context. While the second one calls the function within a new `{}` context. Yet the `this` in your anonymous function will not refer to the new `{}` context, since it is called within the `window` context since `add()` is the same as saying `window.add()`.

For debugging purposes, try adding some alerts or console.logs into your function:

```
function Add(x) {
    alert('The context Add was called with is: '+this);
    this.counter = x;
   return function () {
alert('The context the anonymous function was called with is '+this);
return this.counter += 1;}
};
```

Then you'll see what `this` points to.  When `window.counter` is undefined, you're getting NaN since `return this.counter += 1;` is adding 1 to `undefined` resulting in `NaN`.

As far as solutions, one option is to `bind` the function to the context you want it called in:
http://jsfiddle.net/eu9r8pau/4/

Another option is to take advantage of closures by storing a reference to this:
http://jsfiddle.net/eu9r8pau/5/

You can also rewrite the code to something simpler:
http://jsfiddle.net/eu9r8pau/6/

Comment: Thanks for the examples. It's really helpful for me to understand the difference. Actually I am a core java programmer. Unlike Java,  JavaScript's "this" keyword is really confusing!

Answer (score 0):

To add another variation to Dan Lowe's post and explanation, this time with with regards to the title of the OP's example talking about a local variable which I take to mean a private variable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<p>Counting with a local variable.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function Add(x) {
   var counter = x;
   return function () {return counter += 1;}
};
var add = new Add(0);
function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is, I think the classic example of a closure. The variable `counter` stays in the scope of the function `Add` and only the function to increment it is public.

You can use as many instances of `Add` as you want and have as many independant counters. For example add another one starting at 100:

```
var bdd = new Add(100);
function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add() + "<br />" + bdd();
}
```

The "related" column on the right of this page has a good [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1) of Closures, please take a look.